# Date setting not working in react "useState"

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to use the `useState` hook in react and as a default value I want to set an incoming props value (startDate). Unfortunately, it is always setting in the actual/current date. What am I getting wrong here?

My code:

```
 export type CalendarProps = {
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
};

const SomeCalendarView: React.FC = (props: CalendarProps) => {
  console.log(props.startDate);
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(props.startDate);
  console.log(selectedDay);
  ....
```

My console log:
[image: Console Log]

May 12 - is my incoming startDate.

May 14 - is my current date/time.

Why I am  getting the actual time? Any ideas?

Comment: Use `new Date`.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, unfortunately, it gives the same result. Tried with "useState(new Date(props.startDate))"

Comment: where are you using this component?

Comment: @Hunor I couldn't reproduce it (https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-night-ofy09?file=/src/App.js). If you can reproduce the issue and share the link, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware, that my props dates (`startDate` and `endDate`) are coming with a delay and the `useState` default is getting value instantly (and because the props date was not available, it was populated with the actual/current date). I had to use `useEffect` to set my state as soon as the props are changing. Like here:

```
const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState();
const [selectedStage, setSelectedStage] = useState();

useEffect(
  () => {
    setSelectedDay(props.startDate);
    setSelectedStage(props.stages.valueSeq().first());
  },
  [props.startDate, props.stages],
);
```

Comment: I don't think this is really doing what you think it is. useEffects second parameter is an array of variables to act on whenever they update and useEffect only triggers if those variables update so in reality the props might change but useEffect already triggers whenever any property is updated since it fulfills the functionality for componentDidUpdate. Instead of that you can just pass in an empty array [ ] and that will produce the same effect (no pun) since this represents your component mounting/unmounting.